# MVC CMS site "textboxfor" styled to look like plain text until clicked on

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to build a CMS type website that can be edited by simply clicking on the different text fields when in an edit mode.

The problem is, I don't want the default text box styling formed when you use the `TextBoxFor` code.

Is there a way that I can format the 'TextBoxFor' code in Razor to look like normal static text, but still keep them editable. I need to use the existing CSS classes that would be used on the main site.

The reason for this would be to give a real-time preview of what the site would look like while the user is editing it.

[image: Template]

So for example, each of these text fields in the image (populated from a model) need to be editable but the edit box to do so should look like plain text.

Is this possible? I am using .NET MVC 4...

Comment: Use a css `:focus` psuedo class to style the element when its focussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor does simply generate HTML.
So what you can do is to tell razor to render the input with a class or an ID.

For example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property, new { @class = "your-class" })
```

Then you can style your textbox according to your needs, using CSS.

```
.your-class:focus{
   //your style here
}
```

Also, Razor is very helpful, but can in some cases be to static. 
Sometimes you have to use plain HTML to achieve your goals.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contenteditable` of `HTML5` please find below example to understand how it works.

Read more about `contenteditable` [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable)

```js
$('.edit').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('.box').addClass('editable');
  $('.text').attr('contenteditable', 'true');  
  $('.save').show();
});

$('.save').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('.box').removeClass('editable');
  $('.text').removeAttr('contenteditable');
  $('.edit').show();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  background: url(https://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/wood_pattern.png);
}

h3 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 30px 10px 5px;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
}

.editable {
  border-color: #bd0f18;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #555;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.text {
  outline: none;
}

.edit, .save {
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.edit { 
  background: #557a11;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

.save {
  display: none;
  background: #bd0f18;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.box:hover .edit {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>inline editing with contenteditable & jquery</h3>
<div class="box">
  <span class="edit">edit</span>
  <span class="save">save</span>
  <div class="text">
    Hover this box and click on edit! - You can edit me then.
    <br>When you finished - click save and you saved it.
    </div>
</div>
```